# Solr search statistics in category scale

Tags: solr

I need to implement further functionality picture of it is attached below. I've already built an application based on Solr search. 
In a few words about this functionality: drop down will contain similar search phrases within concrete category and number of items found. 
In what way to make Solr collect such data and somehow receive it?

[image: Similar searches]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that in Solr using Facets, which allow grouping results. The default behaviour of facets is to return the group name and the number of items found. You do that by adding these 2 items you your query string `facet=true`, `facet.field=category`.

An example query in your case will be

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/NAME_OF_YOUR_INDEX/select/?wt=json&indent=on&q=ipo&fl=category,name&facet=true&facet.field=category
```

Take a look at [the tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/tutorial.html) for more details.

This is roughly equivalent to doing this in SQL:

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE text LIKE "%ipo%" GROUP BY category;
```